# How do I constantly check if something on a server (Parse) has changed without thousands of requests?

Tags: swift, database, parse-platform, pfquery

I am creating an application which has a follow mechanism where the followed user has to accept the request of a following (similar to private accounts on instagram).

I then want the following user to find out when the other user has checked a million times (every time the following user opens the screen if I did the query in viewDidLoad). However, the problem with this, is that there will be a lot requests which will expensive to me as I will have to pay for the requests to Parse so I want to minimise these queries.

Currently, the best thing I can think of is to check once a day at midnight for example but this doesn't seem very seamless.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "as I will have to pay for the requests to Parse". Parse.com is shutting down in 3 months

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I pay for the amount of requests to Parse open source but pay to AWS, the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters consider how stale you are willing to allow an app's view of the world to be and cache the response that long. If a user views that screen every 30 seconds you might only want to actually check with the server 5 minutes after the last successful response (or the last response which had 0 follow requests).

You might consider switching from this sort of "pull" polling where the client decides when to ask the server if anything has changed to a "push" model where the server can inform the client when a change occurs. For example you can send a silent background push notification to a user's devices when they have a follow request, the app can then respond by performing your existing query.

You might still want polling or user triggered requests (like a "pull to refresh" gesture) as a fallback for missed notifications or devices with notifications disabled but you should be able to drastically reduce request volume.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response @Jonah. I think the idea of using a silent push system sounds like a really efficient way of handling it. I'm not too well versed in it, but will definitely look into it. Thanks again